# Changing the background image of property page - MFC

Tags: mfc

Can anybody tell me if there is any way of adding a background image to property page in MFC? I'm able to set the background image for dialog but not able to do the same for property page?

Answer (score 0):

Inherit `CPropertyPage` and override `OnEraseBkgnd`. You can paint a bitmap into the provided device context.